# How did they write MSVC++ Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“C or gcc” is like “Chicken or the egg” ? :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11798506/c-or-gcc-is-like-chicken-or-the-egg)

if the visual c++ debugger is the tool for debugging a running program, what debugs the debugger while it's developed?
Chicken Egg dilemma ? How did they debug Visual C++ Debugger ?

Comment: It is not **the** tool for debugging, it is **a** tool for debugging.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429491/how-are-gcc-g-bootstrapped

Answer (score 5):

They use the previous known good build of the debugger to debug it. This is like how the Visual C++ compiler is written in Visual C++- they use VC++9 to develop VC++10. This kind of tool bootstrapping isn't unusual.

Comment: Probably so simple they didn't really need a debugger.

Comment: I used an in-house developed 1.0 C compiler for the TI-9900 chip for a commercial product.  The compiler was developed and ran on the VAX/VMS using DEC's C-compiler (yes, the TI compiler was written in C), but the compiler targeted a TI-9900 based micro computer.  You will probably need to ask K&R how the first, first C compiler was developed.

Comment: @franji - The first C compiler was written using the B compiler they had written earlier. Seriously! ;-)