# Is LLVM/Clang bootstrapped/compiled by GCC?

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

There is a term that [compiler bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) which fundamentally means `compiling a new compiler with old compiled compiler`. For example, even GCC is firstly compiling by a little part of GCC and [so forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429491/how-are-gcc-and-g-bootstrapped).

So, the question, is LLVM/Clang bootstrapped/compiled by another compiler like GCC or written from scratch and if, basically how? I can see some traces of GCC in LLVM library intuitively but I couldn't find exact proper information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. LLVM can be compiled using any of a large number of compilers. When I cared about such things there were dozens of independent compilers. (Remember that only correctness matters — you can bootstrap using even the slowest compiler, that produces the slowest output and has shitty diagnostics.)

This legend has a basis though: On many systems, LLVM asks GCC about how to invoke the system linker, which can be fiddly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood that we can compile any LLVM project with any compiler but for example doesn't Clang have a predefined compiler? When I installed Clang as a package directly (not cloning and building library) to my pc (e.g. on linux `sudo apt install clang`) isn't it already compiled by another compiler like gcc or that I don't know? Actually, that is what I intended to ask in the broad sense.

Comment: It's compiled by something or other. It may have been compiled by clang, even, either the previous version of the same debian package or by cross-compiling from another platform. These things usually involve several steps and can be quite tricky.

Comment: An example: Suppose you need clang for FumbleOS, and you have no compiler at all there. But you have a laptop running Windows. So you build clang on Windows (using Microsoft's compiler, or a clang you downloaded). When you see that that works, you change clang's CMakeLists.txt to compile for FumbleOS instead of Windows, and build clang again, producing a compiler for FumbleOS that runs on Windows. Next you use the second clang to build clang a third time, producing a FumbleOS executable that you can transfer from your laptop to the target. Tricky, but possible from almost any starting point.